# Deploy Azure Machine Learning models using Custom Docker Image on Azure Container Regisrty

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, docker, azure-machine-learning-service

I want to train **Azure Machine Learning model** on azure using **Azure Machine Learning Service.** But I want to use the **custom Docker image** for deploying the model on azure. I am not able to understand how to deploy Machine Learning models using Custom Docker Image.

Please share me if there is any tutorial or blog about the deploy ml models using a custom image.

Please check the below Docker file commands:-

```
# Set locale
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install locales
RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
RUN update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8

# Install MS SQL v13 driver for PyOdbc
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN apt-get install apt-transport-https
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - 
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
RUN exit
RUN apt-get update

RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql
RUN apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev
```

I want to use the **Azure Container Registry** for push the docker image and use the **Custom Docker Image.** Please let me know if there is any way.

**Is there any way to Deploy Azure ML Models using Custom docker images?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do following:

1. Create an [Environment][1] with the coordinates of your custom Docker image specified in Docker section.
2. Create [InferenceConfig][2] with that Environment as argument, and use it when deploying the model.

For example, assuming you have a model already and eliding other arguments:

```
from azureml.core.environment import Environment
from azureml.core.model import InferenceConfig

env = Environment(name="myenv")
env.docker.base_image = "mybaseimage"
env.docker.base_image_registry.address = "ip-address"
env.docker.base_image_registry.username = "my-username"
env.docker.base_image_registry.password = "my-password"

ic = InferenceConfig(…,environment = env)
model.deploy(…,inference_config = ic)
```

```
  [1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.environment.environment?view=azure-ml-py
  [2]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.model.inferenceconfig?view=azure-ml-py
```

Comment: @Roope_Astala Can you please share me more details on above? If you have any steps, then please share me. I have created the docker image it's on the docker hub. I want to use this image.

Comment: I added more details to answer. If you're using docker hub, you won't need the username and password information in docker.base_image_registry section.

Comment: @Roope_Astala I am trying to use a docker hub image. But I got below error `Specified base docker image godaseakshay/azuremlpyodbc not found`.

Comment: @Roope_Astala Above comment issue solved from me. I have added Tag in `godaseakshay/azuremlpyodbc:azure_ml_pyodbc_new`. It's work now properly

Comment: @Roop_Astala I have successfully registered the models using a custom docker image. but I am trying to deploy the model on azure but I got timeout error.  Can you please help me. I am not able to understood why it takes lots of time.